# How to properly add an attachment with an email, specifically an RTF in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a project that has a feature to edit data in a UITextView and then email the text in that UITextView in an RTF file format. I got everything to work, and even being able to attach the data and send it via email. The problem comes when I try to download the file and open it on my computer, it says "The document could not be opened". However, when I use the Gmail preview, I can see that the text is in the file.

So I'm wondering if there is a settings or option that I am missing in my code to "complete" the RTF file? Or if there is a more proper way than how I am doing it. Here's what I'm doing:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"EMAIL TEST"];

// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"Send RTF";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

NSData *dataString = [[myTextView text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[picker addAttachmentData:dataString mimeType:@"text/rtf" fileName:@"rtfFileName"];

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I understand that I can use the mimeType "text/plain", which creates a text file that I am able to open when I email it to myself. But I would like to have an RTF file instead. Thanks for looking and responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually have any RTF to attach to the email. The `text` property of a text view is simply plain text.

You need to convert the text view's `attributedText` to RTF. This can be done as follows:

```
NSAttributedString *attrStr = myTextView.attributedText;
NSError *error = nil
NSData *data = [attrStr dataFromRange: NSMakeRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length]) documentAttributes:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType } error: &error];
if (data) {
    [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/rtf" fileName:@"rtfFileName"];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you rmaddy... That should have been obvious to me that my data was just "text" and that's where my investigation should have started.